# Why does the compiler not give error when we have public methods inside default class

Tags: java, oop, access-modifiers

Why does the JAVA compiler not give error when we have public methods inside default class ?

When we have non public classes (lets say with default access level) and if we have public methods within that class as follows ,

```
class Main {

    public void doStuff() {

    }
}
```

then we cannot access above doStuff() method from outside of the same package. But it is legal to have public access modifier for above method deceleration. So what is the purpose of it ?

Comment: methods can be called via reflexion, also - afair javac gives notice in this case

Comment: because in the olden days of Java you could `import` from the default package; thats they great thing about backwards compatibility, it hamstrings the future for generations for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not an error, and because it could be necessary to *avoid* an error: for example, if it's an implementation of an interface method.

Answer (score 2):

There is no harm in allowing `public` access to members of classes with package visibility: there is no contradiction in defining it this way, so the compiler allows it.

However, you are certainly right that making a member of a package-visible class `public` does not expand its visibility: if the owning class has package visibility, making all its public members package-visible as well is not going to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody in the same package could instantiate a Main, and pass it to another class as a Object or an Interface.  In the former case methods like toString() and equals() must be public, in the latter methods of that Interface must be.